# How do I control which fields get serialized in Axis2?

Tags: apache-axis

How do I control which fields get serialized in Axis2? I have some fields (really getter/setter pairs) that I don't want exposed to the client. Also, some are coming across as nullable (e.g. someIntSpecified properties are created) where I want them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is unfortunately no annotation to exclude attributes from getting serialized.

I think you will need to create Data Transport Objects (DTOs). Otherwise you won't have a clean separation between your core business objects and the objects that you expose as API.

Comment: Sigh, once again a Java library has ten thousand extension points and none of them cover the basic use cases.

Comment: Hm I don't know, I think that the most of the developers of Axis2 think the other way round: They create some WSDL with some tools and then edit the XML manually if required. That way they can get exactly what is needed.